# How to remove underline from "Input" in react-native IOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have suffering from one problem that is my textfields has a underline in ios.
i have used "Input" from native-base.
i have also put

```
underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
```

but still issue is there.

help me to sort out this.

Thank you.

Comment: it would be helpful if you created a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

try setting following props to TextInput component and change them as your needs:

```
<TextInput
    autoCorrect={false}
    autoCapitalize={'none'}
    keyboardType={'web-search'}
    returnKeyType={'search'}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using NativeBase and I remove the underline in ios by

```
<Input style={{borderBottomWidth:0}}/>
```

I think it should be same for TextInput.